# How to provide input for a (fortran) program started with os.system() or another python function?

Tags: python, os.system

I am creating a python script that runs a fortran code multiple times using different input values. I have tried running the fortran code using: `os.system('./fortrancode')`. However, the fortran code then asks for new user input. This has to be provided over multiple lines (multiple read statements in the fortran code) in the following format:

[run fortran code]

filename_input.txt [press enter]

filename_output.txt [press enter]

1 [press enter]

1 [press enter]

1 40 [press enter]

-10 [press enter]

At the moment I am unable to provide the fortran code with these input parameters from my python script. (Probably because os.system() is waiting for the terminal to do an output?) I've also tried to do `os.system('./fortrancode\nfilename_input.txt\nfilename_output.txt\n1\n1\n1 40\n-180\n')`, but that didn't seem to work either.

What would be the correct way to provide the fortran code with the input parameters I'm looping over in the python script?

Comment: You have two options, use subprocess.Popen and comunicate with pipes, or if things get hairy use pexpect https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ for your case, the Popen with pipes should suffice

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1:

```
import subprocess 
result = subprocess.Popen(['./fortrancode', 'filename_input.txt','filename_output.txt','1', '1', '1', '40', '-180'])
```

Solution 2:

You can call from python using [F2PY](https://www.numfys.net/howto/F2PY/)